For what $x_1,...,x_{20}\geqslant0$, with $\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i^2=1$ and $x_0:=x_{20}$ , is $\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-x_{i-1}x_i}< \sqrt{20\times19}$?
For $n=1,...,19$, and $x_1,...,x_n\geqslant0$, with $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=1$ and $x_0:=x_n$, it is conjectured that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-x_{i-1}x_i}\geqslant \sqrt{n(n-1)}.$$
According to MSE contributor @RiverLi, who introduced MSE users to the inequality, it fails for $n\geqslant20$. River Li provides a link to a Chinese website, which appears to provide a source reference for this failure, but I am unable to follow it.
Thus I am led to the question: can a contributor here provide a readable link for the counterexample when $n=20$, or even provide the $20$ numerical values?

I also wanted to get a hold of that document in English by Xuezhi (? misspelt most likely ) of 10 inequalities but have not been able to.

By setting all except one $x_i$ to $10^{-6}$ or smaller, and the remaining one to nearly 1, can't we get arbitrarily close to 20?

The doc merely says that (in red text for question 3) "on Mar 30 2012, a teacher computationally showed that it doesn't hold for $n \geq 20$. As for $ 5 \leq n \leq 19$, we do not know if it holds."

@dezdichado Note that it's just a list of inequality conjectures, and doesn't provide any explicit proofs, and just states where you can find the proof (often is in a book that I guess the author wrote) So you can look at the math symbols and reasonably accurately guess the inequality, then try to prove it. Questions 3, 4, 13, 22ii have not been determined. Note that not all of them are true.

@IvanNeretin : We are permitted zero values for the $x_i$; so $x_1=\cdots=x_{19}=0$ with $x_{20}=1$ is possible. Thus we can get $20$ for the sum, which satisfies the inequality. The point, though, is that the inequality fails for some valid choice of $x_1,...,x_{20}$.

Two solutions for $n\ge 20$ by YAN Wenlan are given in: Solutionn 1, Solution 2. I also have a solution for $n\ge 20$.
